# How to add static files to jar using Gradle build in Spring Boot + Angular 2 project

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, heroku, gradle

I have a Spring Boot + Angular 2 project. I want to deploy it to Heroku.
I'm able to run the npm build then copy the generated files over to the public folder (src/resources/public) manually, then run the backend build.
What I want to do is to set up a gradle build that will do all of that at once. 
What I have so far is a gradle build that will build the front end, build the backend, however it does not copy the static files before generating the jar. Since the jar does not contain said static files, it won't work on Heroku.

Here's the project folder structure:

```
root
 backend
  src/main/java
  src/main/resources
 frontend
  --> angular files go here
 build/libs -> where the JAR file goes
```

The gradle build file:

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    // spring
    classpath('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.2.RELEASE')
    classpath('org.springframework:springloaded:1.2.6.RELEASE')
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.moowork.node" version "1.2.0"
}

// gradle wrapper
task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.4'
}

// configure gradle-node-plugin
node {
    version = '8.1.4'
    npmVersion = '5.0.3'
    download = true
    workDir = file("${project.projectDir}/node")
    nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}/")
}

// clean node/node_modules/dist
task npmClean(type: Delete) {
    final def webDir = "${rootDir}/frontend"
    delete "${webDir}/node"
    delete "${webDir}/node_modules"
    delete "${webDir}/dist"
    delete "${webDir}/coverage"
    delete "${rootDir}/backend/src/main/resources/public"
}

// clean task for npm

task copyFiles {
    doLast {
        copy {
            from "${rootDir}/frontend/dist"
            into "${rootDir}/backend/src/main/resources/public"
        }
    }    
}

// build task for npm
task frontendBuild {}
frontendBuild.dependsOn(npm_install)
frontendBuild.dependsOn(npm_run_build)

npm_install {
  args = ['--prefix', './frontend']
}

npm_run_build {
  args = ['--prefix', './frontend']
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs = ['backend/src/main/java']
        }
        resources {
            srcDirs = ['backend/src/main/resources']
        }
    }
}

copyFiles.dependsOn(frontendBuild);
compileJava.dependsOn(frontendBuild);

task backendBuild {}
backendBuild.dependsOn(compileJava)
backendBuild.dependsOn(jar)

jar.dependsOn(copyFiles)

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

eclipse {
    classpath {
         containers.remove('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER')
         containers('org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/JavaSE-1.8')
    }
}

idea {
    module {
        inheritOutputDirs = false
        outputDir = file("${buildDir}/classes/main/")
    }
}

jar {
    baseName = 'expense-splitter'
    version = '0.0.1'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

configurations {
    dev
}

dependencies {
    // spring
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.2.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:1.5.2.RELEASE')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.5.2.RELEASE')

    compile('org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2')

    // to make hibernate handle java 8 date and time types correctly
    // it's marked as deprecated but we need to keep it until
    // spring boot jpa starts using hibernate 5.2
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-java8:5.1.0.Final')

    // json web tokens
    compile ('io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.7.0')

    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    // google gson
    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0')
    // jackson - parsing of java 8 date and time types
    compile('com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.8.7')


    // spring dev tools
    dev('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools:1.5.2.RELEASE')

    // testing
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:1.5.2.RELEASE')
}

// run spring boot app
bootRun {
    //addResources = true
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath + configurations.dev
    jvmArgs = ["-Xdebug -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,address=8080,server=y,suspend=n"]
}

// run all task
task runAll {}
runAll.dependsOn(bootRun)
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Try a different approach. Instead of manually copying the resources, tell Gradle that when it processes resources for the JAR, also take into consideration what is in `frontend/dist/`:

```
processResources {
    from ('frontend/dist/') {
        into 'public'
    }
}
```

This should result in a JAR containing a `public/` directory, with the contents of `frontend/dist/` inside of it.

Comment: Would the war file need some more modification?

Answer (score 7):

**Gradle configuration for Spring Boot 1.5\2.x + Angular 2-6**

Angular in sub-folder `frontend`

**Frontend module**

Crate `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
  id "com.moowork.node" version "1.2.0"
}

node {
  version = '8.11.3'
  npmVersion = '5.6.0'
  download = true
  workDir = file("${project.buildDir}/node")
  nodeModulesDir = file("${project.projectDir}")
}

task build(type: NpmTask) {
  args = ['run', 'build']
}

build.dependsOn(npm_install)
```

**Note for Angular 6**

Update `outputPath` value in `angular.json` to 'dist'

**Backend module**

Edit `build.gradle` for backend module:

Spring Boot 2.X:

```
bootJar {
    archiveName = "yourapp.jar"
    mainClassName = 'com.company.app.Application'

    from('frontend/dist') {
        into 'static'
    }
}
```

Spring Boot 1.5.X:

```
jar {
    archiveName = "yourapp.jar"
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'com.company.app.Application'
    }
    from('frontend/dist') {
        into 'static'
    }
    from {
        configurations.compile.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
}
```

Finally execute `bootRepackage` or `bootJar` task and check results in `builds/libs`

Comment: bootJar worked for me. I liked it better as i want to copy my compiled react js files only when i am bundling into a jar. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that front end is located at the following folder: `src/main/webapp/fe-ui/`, the following solution for the Spring Boot version 2.1.1.RELEASE could be considered:

```
bootJar {
    baseName = 'jar-name'
    version = '0.1.0'
    from('src/main/webapp/fe-ui/build') {
        into 'public'
    }
}

task installFeDependencies(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['install']
}

task buildFe(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['run', 'build']
    dependsOn installFeDependencies
}

compileJava {
    dependsOn buildFe
}
```

Running `gradlew build` will install, build front end as well as will invoke `bootJar`. The latter will package built front end bundle.